# How do I have my discord bot DM me when someone says a specific command?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have searched for awhile and haven't found a definitive answer. I have my main code setup and all that, and have seperate files for each command, so this is my basic code format. I am simply looking for someone being able to say "!alert" as a command, the bot will respond with "(Username) has been alerted" and then the bot will DM myself with "(Username) has requested your attention." If y'all need more information, thats fine, I'm new to this.

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'alert',
    description: "alert",
    execute(message, args){
      '#code goes here obv'
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

There are three steps to the command you want to build.

- You have to fetch your user object through the client
- You have to send a message in the channel the command was sent in saying you were alerted
- You have to then actually dm the person and display the details of whoever sent the command.

---

First, you'll need to fetch your user object. For that, of course, you'll have to access the client and it's collection of users. Fortunately, you can find your instance of the client through the `message` object.

Also, since v12, discord.js uses `Managers`, which means we'll have to use the cache property before we try to get your user details. Remember to put the found object in a variable, since we'll be using it more than once.

```js
// your user object
const owner = message.client.users.cache.get('Your ID Here');
```

**Links:**

[`Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=client) -> [`Message.client`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=client) -> [`Client.users`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=users) -> [`UserManager.cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserManager?scrollTo=cache) -> [`Collection.prototype.get()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=get)

---

Now you need to send a confirmation message to the channel, for which you can just use the plain `message.channel.send()`. However, you'll also want to show your username in the message.

Since you're always going to be the one who's alerted, you could just write down your username... But that's not very fun, so I suggest you get it through the `owner` object.

```js
// send the message to the channel
message.channel.send(`${owner.username} has been alerted.`);
```

**Links:**

[`Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=client) -> [`Message.channel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=channel) -> [`TextChannel.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) -> [`User.username`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=username)

---

Lastly, you'll have to dm yourself (`owner`) with the username (although I think the tag would be better, as it shows the discriminator as well; imagine how many people have the same discord username) of the person who sent it. That can be found within the `message.author` property.

You can dm anyone by calling the `send()` method on their [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) or [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) objects, just as you can call the `send()` method on any [`TextChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel) or [`TextBasedChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send).

```js
// dm you
owner.send(`${message.author.tag} has requested your attention`);
```

**Links:**
[`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) -> [`User.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=send) -> [`Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) -> [`Message.author`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author) -> [`User.tag`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=tag)

Answer (score 0):

You could go something along these lines:

```js
let guild = client.guilds.cache.get('serverID')
let user = guild.members.cache.get('yourUserID')
user.send('message')
```